# PHP PDO Multiple Result sets in one query or multiple separate queries

Tags: php, sql, pdo, orm

I am just finishing a simple PHP Framework for a University project and I am trying to create a simple Data Access Object per entity which encapsulates all Database interaction and I am not going to use Doctrine or another tool for this, I need to do it myself, It needs to be simple but robust, I will try keep my question as clear as possible.

I want to create one DAO class per entity so it acts as a bridge between a table and an entity.
I am learning a bit from Doctrine but cant find enough information.

Since I have a Dao class per entity obviously all DB logic will be in the Dao, the entity will have pure domain logic, Each Dao is responsible for creating entities and all read/write operations to data layer

My main question is what is the best and most efficient way to load entity associations especially if I wish to load the FULL ASSOCIATION?,

I am trying to understand how this lazy and eager loading works under the hood for entity associations, (not partial columns)

If I just want a column I could use a join but If I want the whole entity the only way I see this being possible is to either make another query to the database or use multiple queries in one execute statement with rowset to fetch the associated entity.

What if I have many associations, what if the database is on a different machine? I want to keep it as flexible as possible but I do not want unnecessary complexity,
Are there any significant differences in performance?

Especially as if I am getting multiple entities from different tables, If I have to issue multiple queries, is there any real difference between lazy and eager loading? As there are more or less the same queries being made,

I will use the simple example of an Article and Comments 1:many relationship as an example:

```
//Article Entity example, Assume each property maps to a column in a database
class Article extends Entity
{
    private $id;
    private $title;
    private $body;
    private $comments = [];

    //Getters/Setters:
    public function get_comments()
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }
}

class Comment extends Entity
{
    private $id;
    private $title;
    private $comment;
    private $user_name;
    private $created_at;
    private $updated_at;
    private $edited = false;
    //
}

//dao class example:
class ArticleDao extends SQLDao
{
    private $one_to_many = [
       'comments' => [
            //metadata here
        ],
    ];
}
```

Now the comment entity / table has have Different columns/attributes so if I want the whole thing its a different set so a join is not possible I guess?

suppose I want to get a bunch of articles or one article and I want their associated comments which are a simple array/collection of comment entities, what is the most efficient way to go about this?

I feel the only options I have are:

1) Create a multi query multiple result set where I fetch everything at once,
I could use my query builder and the Dao class can have a neat wrapper around it,
Something like:

```
$article_dao = new Dao();
$article_dao->where('id','=',$id)->with('comments')->get();
//Creates two queries:
SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE id = :id,
SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE Comments.article_id = id,
//use nextrowset:
//Populate entities and initialise objects:
```

Option 2: Add the dao object and a load method to the comments variable and create some kind of callback which calls the method the first time the comments property is accessed,
The code below is mainly just a rough version:

```
//Base Dao Class method:
public function load_relation($relation, $id):array
{
    //Checks if relation exists and is defined
    if(!$this->has_relation($relation))
    {
        return false;
    }

    /*Initialises the Comment Dao class
    and calls the method and passes parent id */
    return $this->get_relation($relation)['dao']->get($id);

}

//Base entity class load method:
public function load($prop)
{ 
    Check if the property in the entity has a dao object
    if(is_a($this->$prop[0], IDao::class))
    {
         //Call that method which makes a query to the database
         $entities = call_user_func($prop);
    }
    //Now the array has been populated
    $this->$prop = $entities;
    //reuturn
    return $this->$prop;
}

//Now in the article entity, I could use this:
public function get_comments()
{
    return $this->load('comments');
}
```

Or is there a better option?

Is there a major performance advantage to use multiple queries with nextrowset instead of just a clean new query?
The latter seems a lot simpler and my code will be cleaner

I have already created a base query builder library I will use with the dao

Maybe I have missed the whole point, I do not know how these ORM's work but I wanted to create a good platform

any advice would be appreciated, im sorry if my question sounds complex, happy to elaborate/simplify as best I can if needed

Comment: If you care about performance, you generally don't use an ORM.  The pattern I prefer is the repository pattern.

Comment: I have a repository I have implemented inside the dao, Maybe I can have a separate class for it, thanks for this, as far as querying the db goes, without ORM, do you use raw sql in this case? All I am really doing is adding FETCH::CLASS to the request which maps to entity

Comment: By raw SQL, do you mean PDO/mysqli or something else?  I use FETCH::CLASS frequently in conjunction with PDO and it works very well.  Why isn't the DAO the same thing as the Repository class?  I am not sure I fully understand your question due to the terminology being used.  As far as the single vs multi-result set, the multi-result will be marginally faster, but I am not sure its going to matter for your use case so just use the simpler approach.

Comment: Try this out: You repository should accept and return an object for most cases except for get.  If that repository has sub items that need another query, call another repository from within the parent one.  For ex: User repository can call the Group repository and fetch a list of groups then attach them to the User object when doing User::get(id); before you return the User object. It takes two queries but its a lot easier to work with and understand.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I meant PDO, I have created a query builder on top of PDO, All it really does is binds the params internally so I do not have to separate them and I can just directly add my variables. The DAO is more or less the same thing, but I read many articles here and in other places and I got the impression that Repository does not do much apart from return simple collections/entities, whereas my DAO does more data manipulation, etc I thought I could always add repository later if needed, Basically right now I have: entity -> DAO -> Db

Comment: Yes that is something I could do, but it still means ultimately I would need to make two separate queries right? there is no way around that I guess?, and if this is the case, (as per your previous comment), I assume you mean it would not matter a lot if I did multiple separate queries VS one query with multiple results?

Comment: Its a trade off in complexity and performance.  Doing it in 1 query is going to be a whole lot of work (and confusion) for very little "performance."  The simpler answer is almost always the better choice.  Only optimize after you create the code and only if it is not fast enough.  At the end of the day, you will get far more optimizing your query than combining two queries into a single result.

Comment: That is very helpful, I thought on similar lines, but I felt if I end up having the DB on a different machine, I did not want to create a huge bottle neck, but you are right, I should get it working first, as it is I have wasted too much time on silly stuf

Comment: The only time you need to worry about database latency from the network is when the database is on a different server __in a different data center.__  If you run into that case, you can use caching like memcached or redis to accelerate you DOA object by creating a caching object that uses the data from the cache if available and calls the DAO object if there is a cache miss.  Php-fig.org has a method of doing this with [PSR-6](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-6/)

Comment: Oh okay, so this is a better solution then combining multiple selects and then having some ugly functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help, I sudo coded out a bunch of stuff but hopefully it gets the idea across.

```
class Article extends Entity
{
    public $id;
    public $title;
    public $body;
    public $comments = [];
}

class Comment extends Entity
{
    public $id;
    public $title;
    public $comment;
    public $user_name;
    public $created_at;
    public $updated_at;
    public $edited = false;
}

class ArticleDao
{
    public function get(int $id): Article {
       // query for article that has primary key $id
       // $object = fetch::class
       $object->comments = (new ArticleCommentDao())->findByArticle($id);
       return $object;
    }
}

class ArticleCommentDao
{
    public function findByArticle(int $articleId): array {
        // query for comments that have foreign key $articleId
        $comments = [];
        // foreach result in resultset
        // $object = fetch::class
        $comments[] = $object;
        return $comments;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty neat, thank you, im just going through it

Comment: I just wanted to ask, what is happening here, is it a lot different to what an ORM would do? I mean the whole proxy object thing, I cant really see the point of it

Comment: Yes, the orm will define and build relationships for you.  You can take a look at the source for [Eloquent ORM](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/) to get an idea of what is happening under the hood.  The "point" is really only to simplify the DAO usage by the programmer so they can get and save objects and have all of the relationships taken care of behind the scenes. You will notice that the ORM code is far more complex to accomplish this.  You can combine the two, but you will need to create a separate ORM code to handle all of the relationship building.

Comment: Thanks, I do not want all that extra stuff, as I can use SQL and might stick with that, at least for my first version, I will stick to manual loading and management of relations for now

Comment: Just did some more digging into this, realised that multi-queries only work when attr_emulate_prepares is true, im keeping it false as even though I am not sure it is true but a lot of people think it is safer to avoid certain types of SQL Injection.  I thought multi-queries would be good to do multiple insert/update/delete operations and it might be more performant, I could lock the tables with transactions